# Растягивание элементов пользователем

Tags: javafx

Нигде не могу найти одну вещь. Как можно сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог сам изменять размеры объекта. К примеру Image. И чтобы во время того, как он его растягивал/уменьшал, перехватывать сразу насколько он растянул/уменьшил этот объект.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду во время выполнения? есть специальное событие мишки, подберите под себя, их довольно много. например вы ждете событие когда нажата кнопка, тогда вы определяете какая сторона растягивается(или вообще нужно ли растягивать) если да то с помошью `event.getX(); event.getY()` можно получить на сколько мишка сдвинулась, это прибавить к текущему размеру. Но это довольно простенький алгоритм и не проработан, возможно будет выбрать болие оптимальный

Comment: также можно использовать StackPane и дать ему border-lenght = 3-5 (по желанию), и добавить обработчик DRAGGER и пименять примерно такую формулу `node.setPrefSize(node.getWidth() + event.getX(), node.getHeight() + event.getY());` также обратите внимание что смотря какой компоненты вы используете, могут быть разные методы получения задачи размера